# get current day in next 12 months

Tags: php, date

Is it possible to get the current day in next 12 months?

Take a look at these scenarios:

```
Today is 2014-05-09
next month will be 2014-06-09
and so on and so fourth

what if today is 2014-01-31
next month is 2014-02-28

Other examples
what if today is 2014-05-31
next month will be 2014-06-30
```

thanks

Comment: It's possible to do *anything*. Would you care to make the question more specific?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the pattern for "day in next month" is. Do you mean "a month later"? "30 days later?" Something else?

Comment: I will just update my question.

Comment: if you require after 30 days then you should go on this link where you can find some hint here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584115/php-strtotime-1-month-adding-an-extra-month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.It will work fine even if date is last day of the month also

```
$date = "2013-03-31";

$d1 = explode("-",$date);

$i = 0;

while ($i < 12)
{

$j = $d1[2];

if(cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $d1[1], $d1[0]) < $d1[2])
$j = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $d1[1], $d1[0]) ;

echo $d1[0]."-".$d1[1]."-".$j."<br>";

$d1[1]++;

if($d1[1] == 13)
{
$d1[0]++;
$d1[1] = 1;
}
$i++;

if($d1[1] < 10)
$d1[1]="0".$d1[1];

}
```

Comment: **Note:** date should be in form `Y-m-d`

Comment: @phphopzter change `if($d1[1] == 12)` to `if($d1[1] == 13)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a DateInterval to the given date. But there is no unified logic in your examples.

For example:

```
$date = new DateTime( '2014-01-31' );
$aMonthLater = clone $date;
$aMonthLater->add( new DateInterval( 'P1M' ) );


var_dump(
    $date->format( DateTime::ISO8601 ),
    $aMonthLater->format( DateTime::ISO8601 )
);
```

This will result in an output like:

```
2014-01-31T00:00:00+01:00
2014-03-03T00:00:00+01:00
```

Thus adding a month will actually add a whole month – you example (skipping from 2014-01-31 to 2014-02-28) does not add a full month.

See [DateTime::add()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)