# How to add month from current date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, monthcalendar

Hi I'm still new in PHP and currently I want to make system about Employee Allowance and have no idea how to start calculate months in php .For example Steve should get allowance for 4 months from now and database stored the result of calculation, so far the coding is:

```
?php
$date=date_create("2013-03-15");
date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("40 days"));
echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
?>
```

Months input is from user and stored in database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14625726/4535386

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow your 40 days versus 4 months, but I think you want something like this:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("Now +40 days"));
```

Comment: it works , but currently i want **"Now +40 days"** is replaced by input by user. For example the input is **5** as integer .  what else i can use besides 'strtotime' ?

Comment: `echo date("Y-m-d",monthAdd(id='period'));`

Comment: `strtotime` takes **almost any** human-readable form you can imagine.  Here is a way to test it online: http://strtotime.onlinephpfunctions.com/  How is the user input being processed?  POST, GET?  Something like this would work fine: `echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Now +".$_POST['period']." days"))`